# How does one get raunchy?

Tags: etymology

*Get* in the question means *derive,* of course. But welcome to the question anyway.

Unusually, it appears that the adjective arrived first and *raunch* is a back-formation from *raunchy.*

However, ODO says

> 1930s: of unknown origin.

and OED isn't a great deal more forthcoming

> Etymology:  Origin unknown.
>   Perhaps compare English regional (west midland and south-western) *raunch* to eat greedily, devour, to tear up, to snatch greedily, and also the related adjective *raunch* (of vegetables) green, uncooked (see Eng. Dial. Dict. at *raunch* v. and adj.).
>   In early use frequently in U.S. military aviation.

Their earliest citation is from a 1937 novel, *I wanted Wings,* apparently published in New York — which may justify "U.S. military aviation", but seems hardly likely to involve English regional dialects. And its usage there,

> You're gigged, Mister. Raunchy shoeshine. Raunchy brass. Raunchy haircut. Raunchy shave.

might be related to an early definition, "Inept, slipshod, slovenly; esp. unkempt, shabby, dirty," [OED] but that shifted fairly quickly to its current meaning, " Energetically earthy and unrefined; sexually explicit or provocative; lewd, bawdy, suggestive" [OED, 1943 citation].

So where does *raunchy* come from? I had thought it might be vaguely onomatopoeic, like *pwhoar!,* but that sexually-charged usage appears to be  derived from the earlier "slovenly", which isn't so far from "sluttish".

*Raunchy* certainly isn't slang **now,** although I suppose it may have been between the Wars. But even slang has some sort of cultural reference to create it. What was it for *raunchy*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Etymonline suggests that its origin may come from the Mexican "***rancho"***, a term which carried a connotation of filth:

[Raunchy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=raunchy) (adj.):

> - 1939, "clumsy, careless, sloppy," U.S. Army Air Corps slang, of unknown origin. ***Origins among cadets in Texas suggest possible connection to Mexican Spanish rancho (see  [ranch](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ranch&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.)), which had connotations of animal filth by 1864.***  Sense of "coarse, vulgar, smutty" is from 1967.

An instance of earlier usage is from "So you're writing a play!" by 
Clayton Meeker Hamilton
Little, Brown, and company, 1935

[Raunchy](https://books.google.it/books?id=vGeFAAAAIAAJ&q=%22raunchy%22&dq=%22raunchy%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBGoVChMIv6GZlqS9yAIVgU4UCh1zawaH) 1935:

> - These plays were written in a raunchy, post-naturalistic style, or presented as political revues and satires. They were written almost entirely by young men..

- also according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raunchy&year_start=1900&year_end=1950&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craunchy%3B%2Cc0) the term was used from the 30's, earlier instances do not appear very meaningful.

Its original meaning from the 30's is:

> - Inept, incompetent, sloppy; unpleasant, contemptible, mean, disreputable; dirty, grubby. -
>
>   - 1939 Forum & Century July 45/1 Depending on how good or how ‘raunchy’ we [sc. Air Force cadets] were, we drilled from one to three hours in the torrid heat.
>   - 1939 Air Corps Newsletter (War Dep.) - Raunchy - a name applied to anything that is dirty or in bad shape.
>   - 1949 Cavalier Daily (Univ. of Va.) 22 Oct. 4/1 This situation could become embarrassing—if the writer in question happened to be well-known as a somewhat raunchy character in reality.
>   - 1953 Berrey & Van den Bark Amer. Thes. Slang (1954) §759/2 Raunchy flying, clumsy flying technique.

Its later meaning

> - *(of persons,) their actions, etc.: boisterous, earthy, sexually provocative, aggressively licentious, suggestive. Also in extended uses, esp. of language, humour, songs, etc.: bawdy, salacious, smutty; tending to excite sexual feeling*, ***appears to have developed during the 60's***:
>
>   - 1967 ‘E. Queen’ Face to Face iv. 17, I fell in love with him. In a raunchy sort of way he's beautiful. 1969 Sat. Rev. (U.S.) 31 May 44/2 A blend of raunchy humor, unpleasant perversity, and..sickening brutality.
>   - 1970 Melody Maker 12 Sept. 7 Most of the songs were too twee, and the rest seemed to be too raunchy. 1971 Sunday Australian 7 Nov. 27/6 Russell now has two albums of his own on which to disport his raunchy rock compositions.
>   - 1973 Daily Colonist (Victoria, B.C.) 23 Nov. 23/1 A drunk at the next table was singing some raunchy songs. The songs kept getting dirtier and dirtier.
>   - 1974 T. P. Whitney tr. Solzhenitsyn's Gulag Archipelago I. i. i. 21 They had noticed two raunchy broads going to bathe. -

Another hypothesis is that the term come from an older US slang very similar term:

***Ranchy***: a.U.S.slang.n(OED)

> - Dirty, disgusting, indecent.
> - 1903 A. M. Binstead Pitcher in Paradise xii. 283 Then they brought the monkey in—the sad-faced, bare-based, flea-ranchy old monk.

Comment: There's a 1939 definition you might want to add to your excellent answer, @Josh61. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gb0tAAAAIAAJ&q=raunchy&dq=raunchy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCGoVChMI6vCuvPy-yAIVBOsUCh0MfAw_